# What is the purpose of this comment inside a region referencing the path of the dll? (System.Action)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, metadata

If I browse to the definition of System.Aciton in VS:

```
#region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v2.0.50727
// C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
#endregion

namespace System
{
    // Summary:
    //     Encapsulates a method that takes a single parameter and does not return a
    //     value.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   obj:
    //     The parameter of the method that this delegate encapsulates.
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //     The type of the parameter of the method that this delegate encapsulates.
    public delegate void Action<T>(T obj);
}
```

Question: What is going on on the first line there? It looks to me almost like some kind of "hack" in place to tell something the physical path of the dll.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a fake file that is automatically generated by VS using Reflection and XML doc comments.

The file path is for your own information.
It can be useful if you're referencing DLLs from different locations in different projects.

Comment: LOL, it had me there for a second... I knew I certainly didn't add it myself! The "metadata]" postfix to the tab-name should have given me a clue :-)