# C# assembly name not found in auto generated file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build a sample C# application in VS2015, but I'm getting the following error. The project has been imported from VS2005:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.RecordingLoaders, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

The issue seems to be referring to the following code in a generated file:

```
#region Assembly Interop.RecordingLoaders, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// S:\coding\CSharp\Example 1\obj\Debug\Interop.RecordingLoaders.dll
#endregion

using ...

namespace RecordingLoaders
{
    ...public class PNRFLoaderClass : IRecordingLoader, PNRFLoader
    { /* Code ... */    }
}
```

I'm far from experienced with C#, but after some Googling I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771356/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-comment-inside-a-region-referencing-the-path-of-the). This seems to suggest that the string in the #region definition is wrong and should be more like:

```
#region Assembly Interop.RecordingLoaders.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// S:\coding\CSharp\Example 1\obj\Debug\Interop.RecordingLoaders.dll
#endregion
```

`Interop.RecordingLoaders.dll` does exist and is in the project folder's `/obj/Debug` folder (I am running in debug mode). This is clutching at straws as this is a generated file and VS is normally very good at this. Any advise how to correct this?

I've tried:

- Targeting both x86 and x64 in case it was a compatibility issue with the dll.
- Placing the dlls in the same folder as the EXE
- Checked I have the correct version of .Net Framework installed

I note that the dll's aren't listed in my `app.config` file. The contents are shown below. If this is the issue how do I added the file here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately I can't provide a full code listing as it requires libraries to be install on the PC. However, the sample code is available from the [HBM](https://www.hbm.com/en/2475/support-downloads-perception/#pnrf-reader-toolkit) website for free. I have tried contacting them for support, but haven't received a reply.

Thanks.

Comment: Your two #region strings are exactly the same.  In any case, it seems like it would be  easy enough to simply add the DLL as a reference to your project.

Comment: No, the `.dll` is not part of the assembly name. Nor are they required to be listed in the `app.config`. Did you try simply copying that file from `obj/Debug` to `bin/Debug`?

Comment: The two dll are already listed in the references section. I can browse them and view their objects.

Comment: @Dark: Yes I did try copying them into bin/Debug.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a combination of the things I tried. The dlls were 32bit AND they needed to be in the bin/Debug folder! I hadn't done both of these together.

Thanks everyone for your time. :)

Comment: If the DLL's are a part of your references, you can make sure they are in the bin folder by setting the "Copy Local" property of each reference to True.

Comment: Good tip. Thanks. :)